# Android: layoutopt error - syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Tags: android, optimization, layout

I'm on a MAC, trying to run the Android layoutopt tool, and when I run the tool on any of my layout files I get the following error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `newline'  
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
```

Anyone else run into this problem? Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: This is only a blind shot, but maybe it's Mac's line ending convention (`\r\n`) instead of Unix convention (`\n`)? Can your editor change line ending mode to "Unix"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like I wrote a bug :) Please file a bug report at b.android.com (please attach the XML file that causes the error) so we can fix it.