# Android Manifest: Syntax error on Line 1

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm putting together my first android app and I've run into what I thought was a simple problem, but I can't find the solution anywhere. When I try to run the code in the emulator I get:

```
AndroidManifest.xml: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
AndroidManifest.xml: line 1: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
```

Here's the first two lines of my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

The manifest syntax looks to be completely correct to me. I'm using Eclipse on OSX, if that matters. The only related question I could find is: 
[Android: layoutopt error - syntax error near unexpected token `newline'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823065/android-layoutopt-error-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-newline)

But there's no answer there, just saying that's a bug and needs to be reported. Is it still a bug?

EDIT: Here's the entire AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="onemorepallet.app"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".OnemorepalletActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: did you try clean your project?

Comment: yessir, hasn't made a difference

Comment: try to copy the manifest to a text file, close the manifest blank, open it back up, paste it back in and then close it and save it then try to run it

Comment: Hmmm. Tried your recommendation, no change.

Comment: Sometimes just closing the project and restarting your machine does the trick, I've had issues with eclipse where its just finicky like that!

Comment: Close your project. Delete your file. Re-create it. Paste your code back in. The most likely problem is an "invisible" character that's throwing off Eclipse...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a blank line about Line 1?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

needs to be the very first line with no blank line above it.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I'd say this is a file encoding problem.  Did you move your project from Linux to Windows or vice-versa?  It seems like it's expecting Linux-style line endings (\n without \r), and you're giving it extra carriage returns (\r) at the end.  Open the file with a hex editor, I bet you'll see there's an extra 0x0D character at the end of every line.